# How to use SpeechContext to Google Cloud Speech

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, speech-recognition, google-cloud-platform

I am integrating Google Cloud Speechem my application and would like to use the SpeechContext features described in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#speechcontext

Does anyone have an idea (tutorial) **how to use this feature SpeechContext**?

Tks!

Thiago

Answer (score 1):

This is how I form the json payload including a SpeechContext to provide key phrases, in this instance "baked potato" and "kerfuffle":

```
{
    "config": {
        "encoding": "LINEAR16",
        "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
        "languageCode": locale,
        "speechContexts": [
            {
                "phrases": [
                    "baked potato",
                    "kerfuffle",
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    "audio": {
        "content": encoded_audio,
    }
}
```

where `locale` is a variable holding the language code and `encoded_audio` is the byte string holding the audio.

Providing this SpeechContext managed nicely to resolve the problems Google Translate had with resolving my application-specific key phrases.